# IPv6 NAT6 and port-forwarding?

Tags: ipv6, openwrt

My local network IPv6 NAT is like:

```
------------------------       ---------------------------------------  
| Web Server:           |     | Router OpenWrt:                      |
| dda1:aaaa:bbbb::221/64| <=> | IPv6 ULA prefix: dda1:aaaa:bbbb::/48 |
|                       |     | br-lan: dda1:aaaa:bbbb::1/60         |
------------------------      | wan6: 2400:xxxx:yyyy::15/64          |
                               ---------------------------------------
```

If I have a web server `http://[dda1:aaaa:bbbb::221]:8080`, how do I configure the `ip6table`
(or something else) on the router so that other people can access it by `http://[2400:xxxx:yyyy::15]:48080`?

And is there any way to configure it in the LuCI WebUI?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Port forwarding is for NAPT, which is explicitly forbidden by the (_experimental_) _[RFC 6296](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6296)_ for IPv6 NAT. The RFC requires a one-to-one NAT: "_Since there is significant detriment caused by modifying transport layer headers and very little, if any, benefit to the use of port mapping in IPv6, NPTv6 Translators that comply with this specification MUST NOT perform port mapping._" IPv6 has enough addresses to give _every_ host or server its own global address, restoring the IP end-to-end paradigm.

Comment: It is true that each device should have its own global IPv6 address and should not use NAT and I'm all for that. But I'm on a very strange network: the upstream server does not respond to IPv6 relay requests. So the devices behind my router can't get their IPv6 addresses. I don't know what to do so I use NAT6 instead :( .

Comment: As I explained before, NAT for IPv6 is a one-to-one NAT that requires a global address for each private address. That means you still must have enough global addresses for each device. It sounds like you need to work with the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is already mentioned in the OpenWrt docs on this page: [NAT6 and IPv6 masquerading](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/ipv6.nat6).

**Note:** I am not sure if this Wiki page has been updated for the newer releases of OpenWrt. I haven't tried it myself, and not sure if it works as expected.

I will briefly outline the steps from the above page, here as well:

1. Configure your WAN interface for IPv6 (refer to [this](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/configuration))
2. Install the [`kmod-ipt-nat6` package](https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/kmod-ipt-nat6).
3. Include [the firewall.d script](https://github.com/akatrevorjay/openwrt-masq6) (that simplifies implementing NAT6 in OpenWrt) using an *include* section in your firewall's configuration.
4. For your WAN zone(s) in the firewall configuration, add a new `masq6` option and set it to `1`.
5. Optionally delete/disable the built-in `Allow-ICMPv6-Forward` firewall rule as it no longer makes any sense.

Now, once NAT6 is successfully implemented, go on to setup port forwarding very similar to how it's done for IPv4 NAT:

1. Set a fixed ULA for your web server device using a static DHCP lease reservation ([use the CLI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration#static_leases) or do it [in LuCI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/luci/static_ip))
2. Add a port forwarding rule specifying the above mentioned fixed ULA address in the `dest_ip` option for the port redirect rule. I believe you'll have to [use the CLI](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/firewall_configuration#redirects) for this, since LuCI (at least in 21.02 at the time of writing) will not let you specify an IPv6 address there.
   If that doesn't work, you can create [a simple script](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/ipv6.nat6#port_forwarding), that creates the DNAT rule using the `iptables` command, and include it in your firewall's configuration.